# Calling Jquery ajax with set interval blocks the page?

Tags: ajax

I have been calling the jQuery ajax function on timely basis by using setInterval function.
so when the first response success handler is called and being executed, 2nd request success handler gets called on after the first response handler gets executed since JAVASCRIPT supports only single threaded...and so on(a queue is maintained to process the success handlers)?? is my understanding correct? so there is chance for page blocking ?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of multiple ajax requests, most browsers handle the ajax request and remember it the next time an ajax request to the same url is called and handle it a second time

```
1st setInterval ajax to abc.html handle [0]
2nd setInterval ajax to abc.html handle [0], [1]
3rd setInterval ajax to abc.html handle [0], [1], [2]
```

it keeps building and adding to the confusion to change this I add an unique identifier to the user e.g

```
$.post("myurl.html?randid="+Math.random(), {my: data}).done(function(data){ /*do stuff here*/});
```

if this is a meant to be loaded for a long time and have a ton of ajax request to the same page instead of just a random number you might want to use a time stamp. for me and most cases the random number works, hope this is enough to get you started.